# Is it possible to build containers from within a container on a system where I am not admin?

Tags: ubuntu, singularity-container

I would like to build singularity recpies locally, rather than relying on Singularity hub and wasting my limited daily build quota on fixing stupid syntax errors. However, I am not admin on the machine where I will be running the containers.  I would like to build a container on Singularity hub, within which I am an admin and can build other other containers. However, my attempts to build a container where I can use `sudo` and `su` make me think this can't be done. Is there any way to set up a container within which I can build containers, and if so what is the problem with my current approach?

I have the following code in my recipe to create a user "ubuntu" with password "ubuntu" and membership in the "sudo" group:

```
Bootstrap:docker
From:ubuntu:xenial
#...some other stuff that doesn't matter here...
%post
apt-get update
apt-get install -y sudo

useradd ubuntu
echo "ubuntu:ubuntu" | chpasswd
usermod -aG sudo ubuntu
```

The recipe builds successfully on Singularity hub.  However, I can't use `sudo` or `su` within the container:

```
$singularity build --sandbox xenial shub://path/to/my/container:xenial
<container builds with some warnings about my account being non-root>
$singularity shell xenial
Singularity: Invoking an interactive shell within container...

Singularity xenial$ su ubuntu
Password:            #I type "ubuntu"
su: Authentication failure
Singularity xenial$ sudo whoami
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
Singularity xenial$ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 hbraunDSP dip 136808 Jun 10 22:53 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Is this just too unsecure to be possible? If it is possible, how do I make a container I can use to build containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singularity mounts `/etc/passwd` by default, so the users available inside the container are the same as the ones on the host machine. So the new `ubuntu` user you added doesn't exist as far as the image is concerned when you're shelled into it.

If you want to build singularity images while running in another one, at minimum you'd need to `sudo singularity shell ...` so you retain your sudo / root privileges.

Alternatively, you can build singularity images from inside Docker containers if you use the `--privileged` option.

Comment: Thanks. "at minimum you'd need to sudo singularity shell ..." answers my question. It's not possible to do what I want to do without sudo privileges on the host machine. I decided to put a virtual machine on my laptop to do builds. Also, good info about mounting /etc/passwd.